# Grails / Groovy - Determine the Source .jar File for a Class

Tags: java, grails, groovy, base64

What is the correct way to write code to do the following:

```
Base64 base64 = new Base64
base64.getClass().getSourcePackageAndVersion() // ???
```

I'm trying to detect in my current Grails project if I am getting Base64 from 
commons-codec-1.3.jar or commons-codec-1.4.jar. Is there a way to force it to use the 1.4 version while in debug / dev mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the jar file or classes directory the class is loaded from with this:

```
base64.getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location
```

or since you already have the class:

```
Base64.protectionDomain.codeSource.location
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is best solved via printing the dependency tree for your dev/debug build via the dependency report (just replace your runtime env):

```
grails dependency-report runtime
```

you can use that information to force your environment to use the correct version of the Base64 class.

Comment: my grails doesn't understand dependency-report

Comment: which grails version are you using? it should be available in 1.x and 2.x also: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html

Comment: sorry was in wrong folder when I first tried to run it. Now I get errors related to ivy when I use the term 'dev' as my environment

Comment: environment names should be the same as in the config.groovy: production / development / test

Comment: hmm. doesn't matter if I use dev or development. I get this error - C:\Users\Owmer\.ivy2\cache\org.grails.internal-testapp-dev.xml does not exist.

Comment: try running it without the environment parameter - that will pick production by default. The report should still be helpful for debugging your library conflicts